# How to mock action in connected component React

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

trying to get familiar with Jest, and I got a bit stuck on the following problem.

I have a component like follow;

```
import { populateBrands } from '../../actions/brand/BrandActions';


export class CampaignForm extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      name: null,
      type: 'a-type',
      brand: null
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.populateBrands({
      payload: {
        filter: {
          organisation: null,
          archived: false
        },
        pageNum: 0
      }
    });

    if (this.props.campaign) {
      const {
        name,
        type,
        brand
      } = this.props.campaign;

      this.setState({
        name,
        type,
        brand: brand.id,
      });
    }
  }


  render() {
   // Render the Form
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  let brands = Selectors.getAllActiveBrands(state);
  return {
    brands
  };
}

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  populateBrands
};

export default withRouter(
  connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(CampaignForm));
```

I want to test something in render, sometimes a drop down is disabled, sometimes it is not, depending on the brands the `populateBrands` function is returning and setting in the state.

What is the best way to test something like that?

So far I have this:

```
it('should display warning', () => {
  const component = shallow(
    <CampaignForm
      processMessage='edit'
      handleSubmit={mockHandleSubmit}
      submitButtonLabel='edit'
      location={'blah'}
      populateBrands={mockPopulateBrands} // mock the function
      brands={fixtureBrands} // pass in the fixture brand data
    />, { context, childContextTypes }
  );

    // do my tests here

});
```

Is this the best way to go? I feel it would be better if I could mock the populateBrands function and return the values I need, rather than do what I am currently do it.

Happy to hear what the best practices are in this scenario

Comment: Similar question answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55579262/testing-connected-components-with-enzyme/55586035#55586035

Comment: mmm I am not sure I completely get it, probably it's best for my case to test the unconnected component, I don't want to test the api calls, I just need to test the behaviour of the component once it has received that data.
But i do need the data, I don't want to check if populateBrands has been called..

Comment: It's more common to test against the unconnected component. Otherwise, if the actions/reducers are being used by multiple components, then you'll be repeating the same test logic that covers the same redux actions/reducers over and over. Instead, you'll test them separately from the component.